# Why does my Flutter app keep sending websocket messages, while it runs in the android background

Tags: android, flutter, dart, websocket, background-service

I wrote a small flutter app, which sends periodically websocket messages (every 15 secounds) to a server. Since the app also should sends this websocket messages when the it runs in the background, I was surprised that this already works without further ado. I thought, all tasks are stopped automatically by android when a app runs in the background.

Here are some related information about my app:

- In the AndroidManifest.xml is only the follwing persission set: , so no foreground or background permission set there
- For the websocket connection, i use the web_socket_channel: ^2.1.0 package

The implemention is as simple as it can be:

```
final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('wss://....'));

timer = Timer.periodic(repeadTime, (timer) {
  sendPeriodicallyWebsocketMessages();
});

sendPeriodicallyWebsocketMessages() {
 channel.sink.add('send data');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may send messages for 1-2 minutes after moving the app in the background. After that, it will stop working.